# Compact matrix integral operator bound via its kernel

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, systems-of-equations, lp-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H} = L^p_{n}(0,a)$, where $p \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $p \geq 1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be the Hilbert space of vector-valued functions defined on the finite interval $(0,a) \subset \mathbb{R}$, $f = (f_1,\ldots,f_n)$, with norm
$$
||f||_{L^p_n(0,a)} = \sum_{i=1}^n ||f_i||_{L^p(0,a)},
$$
and similarly we define, for matrix-valued functions $K \in L^p_{n\times n}(-a,a)$,
$$
||K||_{L^p_{n\times n}(-a,a)}  = \sum_{i,j=1}^n ||K_{ij}||_{L^p(-a,a)}.
$$

Consider a convolution-type integral operator $T_K :  \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$,
$$
(T_K f)(t) = \int_0^a K(t-s)f(s) ds.
$$

Suppose that the kernel is absolutely summable, i.e. $K \in L^1_{n\times n(-a,a)}$. Prove that
$$
||T_K||_{L^p_{n}(0,a)} \leq ||K||_{L^1_{n\times n}(-a,a)}.
$$

Remarks: (i) sources; (ii) what I've tried:

(i) This is an intermediate step (see Lemma 1.1 [following this link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-7643-8956-7_4#page-1)) to prove that under these assumptions, $T_K$ is compact.

(ii) To compute 
\begin{align}
||T_K f||_{L^p_n(0,a)} &= \sum_{i=1}^n ||(Kf)_i||_{L^p_n(0,a)} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \int_0^a |(Kf)_i(t)|^p dt \right)^{1/p} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \int_0^a \left| \sum_{j=1}^n \int_0^a K_{ij}(t-s) f_j(s) ds \right|^p dt \right)^{1/p} \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \int_0^a \left( \sum_{j=1}^n \int_0^a |K_{ij}(t-s)| |f_j(s)| ds \right)^p dt \right)^{1/p}.
\end{align}

Edit 1:
Clearly for $p=1$ it holds, since then by a change of variable,
\begin{align}
||T_K f||_{L^1_n(0,a)} &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \int_0^a \left(  \int_{-s}^{a-s} |K_{ij}(t)| dt \right) |f_j(s)| ds  \\ 
&\leq \sum_{i,j = 1}^n ||K_{ij}||_{L^1(-a,a)} ||f_j||_{L^1(0,a)}.
\end{align}

How to proceed with $p>1$?

Edit 2:
Using (for $p\geq 1$) Holder's inequality with conjugate indices $q$ and $p$, I arrive at
\begin{align}
||T_K f||_{L^p_n(0,a)} &\leq a^{1/p} \sum_{i,j = 1}^n ||K_{ij}||_{L^q(-a,a)} ||f_j||_{L^p(0,a)}.
\end{align}
Which does not solve the problem because in general we have $||K_{ij}||_{L^1(-a,a)} \leq ||K_{ij}||_{L^q(-a,a)}$ for $q>1$.